# Evil twin WiFi station has no internet connection

Tags: networking, linux, wireless-networking

I am trying to create a fake AP using the `airbase-ng` to test how evil twin works.

I have a WiFi adapter TP-link WN4226 [Atheros AR9271 chipset], which supports monitor mode. My laptop (running on Ubuntu 20lts) is connected to internet wirelessly (using WPA-PSK) through its own WiFi adapter.

Here is `ifconfig` before starting the monitor mode:

```
wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Mir_Sahib"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 90:8D:78:0F:FE:CE 
          Bit Rate=150 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-33 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:291   Missed beacon:0

wlxf8d111129a12  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Mir_Sahib"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 90:8D:78:0F:FE:CB   
          Bit Rate=40.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=69/70  Signal level=-41 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:18   Missed beacon:0


enp0s31f6: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 8c:16:45:82:04:49  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 12337  bytes 13508188 (13.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8993  bytes 1146468 (1.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xec200000-ec220000  


wlp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.9  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::7d86:5034:5192:6952  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 5c:5f:67:d0:44:be  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 17280  bytes 16222452 (16.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10496  bytes 1788185 (1.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlxf8d111129a12: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::3ff:6be8:710d:7bf8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether f8:d1:11:12:9a:13  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 264  bytes 34466 (34.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 112  bytes 21293 (21.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I have killed all the processes, which might interfere with monitor mode by `airmon-ng check kill`, I started the monitor mode on my Tp-Link WiFi adapter `airmon-ng start wlxf8d111129a12`, then started the NetworkManager so that my laptop has network connection `service Networkmanger start`.
My TP-Link WiFi adapter changed to wlan0mon which shows the `mode:Monitor` like the following:

```
wlan0mon  IEEE 802.11  Mode:Monitor  Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

I create a fake AP with the command `airbase-ng -e Demo -c 11 wlan0mon`, this command show a fake ap name `Demo` in my phone (Redmi Note 7)

Here is my `dnsconfig.conf` for `dnsmasq`:

```
interface=at0
dhcp-range=10.0.0.20,10.0.0.250,255.255.255.0,12h
dhcp-option=3,10.0.0.1
dhcp-option=6,10.0.0.1
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
server=64.6.64.6
server=64.6.65.6
log-queries
log-dhcp
port=5353
listen-address=127.0.0.1
```

iptable rules:

```
#!/bin/bash
ifconfig at0 up
ifconfig at0 mtu 1500
ifconfig at0 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.0.1
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface enp0s31f6 -j MASQUERADE
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface at0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.11:80
```

I then run the iptables rules and dnsmasq.conf
`dnsmasq -C dnsmasq.conf -d`

My problem is I can connect to the fake AP, but my AP doesn't have any network access, I also tried changing the `--out-interface` to `wlp4s0` which also doesn't work apparently, I have read that a lot of people are using the captive technique using a DHCP server but I haven't tried that. I think I might have a problem with my iptables rules but can't figure out the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "no network access"?

Comment: it means device can connect to the ap but has no internet access

Comment: But that could mean many different things. What are the symptoms? You describe the configuration in great detail. But when asking for troubleshooting support, you also need to describe the *behaviour*. Can you ping the AP? Is there traffic getting to the AP?

Comment: You are also missing details from your configuration. Like, why did you configure your DNS to port 5353? Is the client set up for that port? What is the IP the client is getting? What is `192.168.0.11`? This is not looking like a security question but a networking config question.

Comment: @mirsahib - Please address the feedback you have recieved with regards to your question.

Comment: Also, as a general suggestion: Use Wireshark (if you have a GUI) or `tcpdump` to check what traffic arrives and leaves and whether it matches your expectations of what should be happening.

Comment: I change the DNS port to 5353 cause i am getting a `failed to create listening socket to port 53` even i try to kill the process which is using port 53 but `sys-resolve` always take that port.`192.168.0.11` is my laptop ip assign by my router.

Comment: when i `ping -I at0 www.google.com` i get `From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
`